# How do you change the underlying generator version with the OpenAPI Generator CLI npm package?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

OpenAPITools has an npm package called `openapi-generator-cli`. This package is described as follows on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-cli):

> The OpenAPI Generator is a Java project. openapi-generator-cli will download the appropriate JAR file and invoke the java executable to run the [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

How do you specify the version of the OpenAPI generator (java project) that is used within the npm package?

On the GitHub page, [under the configuration section](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-cli?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration), openapi-generator-cli is shown to be configured via a file called *openapitools.json*. The example config is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "4.3.1" // or the current latest version ;)
  }
}
```

The documentation explains this configuration by saying:

> the generator-cli version 4.3.1 is used

Does generator-cli.version refer to the version of the underlying Java project? I am confused because the npm package is referred to as the `openapi-generator-cli` and the Java project is refered to as `openapi-generator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version refers to the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) version. **Not to be confused with the openapi-generator-cli version**, which has the latest as 2.7.0. For example the following code:

```
{
  "$schema": "node_modules/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/config.schema.json",
  "spaces": 2,
  "generator-cli": {
    "version": "7.0.0" <- refers to the openapi-generator version
  }
}
```

Can be for example version 2.7.0 of the openapi-generator-cli, using the version 7.0.0 of the openapi-generator engine. The version of your project should be configured elsewhere.